# How do you attach a new pull request to an existing issue on github?

Tags: git, github, issue-tracking, pull, pull-request

I'm not sure, but I have a vague memory of creating a github pull request with "Issue 4" or something in the title, and it automatically attached itself to Issue 4 in the project that I was submitting it to. I tried it again recently and it didn't work -- it just created a brand new issue instead. I don't see any options like "Attach to issue" on the new pull request page, nor "Open a new pull request for this issue" on the issue page. Is there any way to do this, to help project owners keep their Issues page clean and avoid duplication?

**Edit**: To clarify, I know that creating a pull request always creates a *new* issue. I would like to instead attach the pull request to an *existing* issue.

Comment: I believe my answer express the fact that the feature you want ("attach a pull request to an *existing* issue") might not be there yet.

Comment: It does (and that is in fact confirmed by [this tweet](http://twitter.com/GitHubHelp/status/18475695785115648)), but it also made me realize my question could have been clearer.

Comment: I hope that feature is high on github priority list, coz the code bears out there would love it!

Comment: The correct answer ought to be changed to masukomi's, now that 
the "fixes #1" method available. No need to go through the API.

Comment: I still cannot find a way to attach a pull request to an existing issue. Have I missed something? The answers in this thread seems to suggest this capability does exist, but I cannot find it (it always makes a new issue).

Comment: The correct answer should be changed to Christian Oudard's answer. While still valuable info, masukomi's answer doesn't actually submit a pull request. It only associates a commit with an existing issue. GitHub has the ability to show whether code is attached to an issue, and this is only done with an associated pull request.

Comment: @RyanMcGeary okay I guess you're right. Switched.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

The [hub](https://github.com/defunkt/hub) project can do this.

In the repository and branch that you want to send a pull request from:

```
$ hub pull-request -i 4
```

This uses the GitHub API, and attaches a pull request for the current branch to the existing issue number 4.

---

**EDIT:** Comment by @atomicules: To expand on the answer by @MichaelMior a full example is:

```
$ hub pull-request -i 4 -b USERNAME_OF_UPSTREAM_OWNER:UPSTREAM_BRANCH -h YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_BRANCH URL_TO_ISSUE
```

Comment: `brew install hub` to install with homebrew

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Says
Error creating pull request: Unprocessable Entity (HTTP 422)

Comment: @Rubycut I had the same problem. Instead I did `hub pull-request URL_TO_ISSUE`, then it worked for me. I wonder if `-i ISSUE_NUMBER` only works if the issue is in the same repository (i.e., not a fork)

Comment: To expand on the answer by @MichaelMior a full example is: `hub pull-request -b USERNAME_OF_UPSTREAM_OWNER:UPSTREAM_BRANCH -h YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_BRANCH URL_TO_ISSUE`

Comment: @atomicules Actually, all I had to do was exactly my command above. This assumes you are sending a pull request for the current branch to the default branch of the upstream repo.

Comment: Note this only works on issues you created: https://github.com/defunkt/hub/issues/189#issuecomment-6353354

Comment: I forked a repo. I created an issue on the upstream repo. I commited a change to my forked repo. I tried to add my change to the issue I created. `-i xx` doesn't work for me. @MichaelMior 's `URL_TO_ISSUE` works.

Comment: @atomicules can we have that as an accepted answer instead of just a comment?

Comment: @chakrit someone could edit the answer to include that info if they deemed it appropriate.

Comment: @atomicules just did that. But honestly I'd rather the reps goes to the one with the most correct answer than the one who simply posted first.

Comment: I had to do `git push -u origin featurebranch`, then `hub pull-request -i 4` worked. ([reference](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/189#issuecomment-6140154))

Comment: `Warning: Issue to pull request conversion is deprecated and might not work in the future.` And indeed, it doesn't work.

Comment: It worked for me, but that deprecation warning still means it's doing away.  Does this mean we're losing this functionality or is github creating some other way to turn issues into pull requests?

Comment: Neither -i or the full issue URL works for me, getting HTTP 422 in both cases.

Comment: Same for me, getting HTTP 422 and "Not allowed to change field "issue""

Comment: Note than in this and many of the answers here, two-factor auth will prevent these from working.  Create a personal access token in your github settings and use it instead of your password ... and voila!  :)

Comment: This has been deprected

Answer (score 258):

Adding a pull request to an existing upstream issue is easy *assuming you forked using the normal github means*.

Simply reference the issue in your commit message using any of the [supported keywords](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages):

- close
- closes
- closed
- fix
- fixes
- fixed
- resolve
- resolves
- resolved

For example: "this commit fixes #116"

The text referencing the issue does not need to appear in the subject line of your commit.

Push your commit to your github repo and the pull request will be automatically appended to the issue.

Note: While it is not required, it is strongly recommended that you commit anything that will be part of a pull request to a separate branch specific to that issue, because future commits on that branch will be appended to the pull request (automatically by github). So, if you didn't make a separate branch, left it on master, and then kept developing, then all your unrelated commits to master would get appended to your pull request.

Comment: "it is strongly recommended that you commit anything that will be part of a pull request to a separate branch specific to that issue, because future commits on that branch will be appended to the pull request" -- very good point. That happened to me once and it was quite surprising.

Comment: This does not solve the problem of turning an issue into a pull request unfortunately. Any discussion that was had in the issue does not get transferred to the pull request... which is unfortunate for several use-cases. I wish Github would just give some granular control over how pull-reqs work in the repo settings.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need an issue turned into a pull request. Why isn't having the pull-request mentioned in the issue's conversation sufficient? This would happen automatically by referencing the # in the pull req. You have a covo thread. Then you have a thread with the relevant pull req embedded in it. Sounds perfect.

Comment: @masukomi A pull request is easier for the project maintainer to resolve – they can accept and merge the changes with the click of a button. To pull a change in a fork without using a pull request, you would have to add the fork as a remote, fetch their changes, and merge them yourself.

Comment: I think you missed my point Rory. If you create a pull request and mention it in the issue (as I suggested), then the two are connected, and you still can click a button to get the changes.

Comment: Reference from GitHub help: https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages

Comment: This doesn't help when the pull request is an on going thing.  Our workflow is to create issues for ideas, and then pull requests from feature branches once we begin work on those ideas.  Closing the issue using a commit in the pull request means we lose the previous discussion that the issue contained, which often includes hashing out whatever feature/fix/refactor the issue addresses.  What is really needed is a way to straight up turn an issue in to a pull request once work on the issue has begun.

Answer (score 144):

You can create a Pull Request from an existing Issue with the [Pull Request API](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#alternative-input):

```sh
$ curl --user "smparkes" \
       --request POST \
       --data '{"issue": 15, "head": "smparkes:synchrony", "base": "master"}' \
       https://api.github.com/repos/technoweenie/faraday/pulls
```

This creates a pull request:

- ask `technoweenie` at project `faraday` (https://api.github.com/repos/***technoweenie***/***faraday***/pulls)
- to pull from the `synchrony` branch in `smparkes`' fork ("head": "***smparkes***:***synchrony***")
- to the `master` branch in `technoweenie`'s fork ("base": "***master***")
- and attach the pull request to issue 15 ("issue": ***15***)
- with the pull request author `smparkes` (--user "***smparkes***")
- you will be prompted for your GitHub password

Comment: I copied in some of the sample code from that link. Hope you don't mind, and please let me know if I mistranslated it!

Comment: You also need authentication, add this to command above: -u "login:password"

Comment: I'd just like to add that this method still works, but it may have the side effect of listing your commit twice on the discussion page, if GitHub had already picked it up implicitly from the issue # in its message ([example](https://github.com/ask/celery/pull/450)). The commit only comes through once on the official pull request, though.

Comment: Can this be updated to the v3 API? GitHub just turned off the v2 API.

Comment: I've also attempted to update this to the v3 API... see if my edit goes through.

Comment: Here’s [an addendum to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11975092/578288). It demonstrates a shorter command using [HTTPie](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie), explains the `smparkes` example in a different way, and includes a password safety tip.

Comment: +1... Just out of curiosity... Where do you write the name of your repository? I see the username and the branch name and from the issue you can get the issues's repository name, but I don't see your repository name. What's happen if you have two repositories with the branch synchrony?

Comment: @xanatos It's determined by the request URL (https://api.github.com/repos/technoweenie/faraday/pulls)

Comment: Is there any way of using this method but have curl (or similar) to ask for your GitHub password rather than typing it on as a command argument in clear text (with all the security concerns that entails)?

Comment: @rsanchezsaez As I say in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11975092/578288), change `--user "smparkes:password"` to `--user "smparkes"` to be prompted for your password interactively.

Comment: Is there a `wget` equivalent? Would it be: `wget --user "smparkes" --post-data 'issue=15&head=smparkes:synchrony&base=master' https://api.github.com/repos/technoweenie/faraday/pulls`? I'm just not sure if the colon in the post-data needs percent-encoding (as `%3A`).

Comment: I had to remove the quotation marks around the issue id. Github seems to require integers now: ```message": "Invalid request. For 'properties/issue', "15" is not an integer.``` so the example becomes: ```curl --user "smparkes" \
       --request POST \
       --data '{"issue": 15, "head": "smparkes:synchrony", "base": "master"}' \
       https://api.github.com/repos/technoweenie/faraday/pulls```

Answer (score 17):

Another possible tool is the **[Issue2Pr website](http://issue2pr.herokuapp.com/)** which turns your issues into Pull Requests.

It's very simple and effective!

[image]

**Resources:**

- **[Announcement](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2012-06-29-introducing-issue2pr)**
- **[GitHub repository](https://github.com/steveklabnik/issue2pr)**

Answer (score 10):

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4529172/578288) explains how to use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) (`curl`) to create a Pull Request from an Issue through the [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/). Here’s how to do it using [HTTPie](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie) (`http`), which produces an easier-to-read and easier-to-edit command:

```
$ http --auth "<your-GitHub-username>" \
       POST \
       https://api.github.com/repos/<issue-repo-owner>/<issue-repo-name>/pulls \
       issue=<issue-number> head=<your-GitHub-username>:<your-fork-branch-name> base=<issue-repo-branch-name>
```

Then type your GitHub password when prompted.

#### Explained example

You have logged into GitHub with username [*smparkes*](https://github.com/smparkes) and password *hunter2*. You saw [*technoweenie*](https://github.com/technoweenie)’s repo [*faraday*](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday), thought of something that should be changed, and made an Issue on that repo for it, [Issue #*15*](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday/pull/15). Later, you find that nobody else has made your proposed change, and you also have some time to do it yourself. You [fork *faraday* to your own account](https://github.com/smparkes/faraday), then write your changes and push them to your fork under a branch named [*synchrony*](https://github.com/smparkes/faraday/branches). You think *technoweenie* should pull those changes to the [*master*](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday/branches) branch of his repo. This is the command you would write to convert your previous Issue into a Pull Request for this situation:

```
$ http --auth "smparkes" \
       POST \
       https://api.github.com/repos/technoweenie/faraday/pulls \
       issue=15 head=smparkes:synchrony base=master
```

```
http: password for smparkes@api.github.com: hunter2
```

Now [Issue #*15*](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday/pull/15) is a Pull Request.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of doing that on the client side (with [`hub`](https://github.com/defunkt/hub), as in [Christian Oudard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3757/christian-oudard) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7841960/6309)), you now (February 2020) can do it on the *server* side (github.com)

See "[View and link issues and pull requests from the sidebar](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-02-04-view-and-link-issues-and-pull-requests-from-the-sidebar/) "

> You can now link issues and pull requests via the sidebar in their respective pages. Connections made here will automatically close issues once a linked pull request is merged.

[Documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/linking-a-pull-request-to-an-issue): [image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/pull_requests/link-issue-drop-down.png]

And there is a [search API](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-02-04-linked-search-qualifier-for-finding-issues-connected-to-pull-requests/) with that feature.

> Find all the open issues in a repository that have closing pull requests references with the `linked:pr` search qualifier.
> Similarly, locate all the pull requests in a repository that are missing a supporting issue with `-linked:issue`.

---

[Ismoh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3493998/ismoh) refers in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528869/how-do-you-attach-a-new-pull-request-to-an-existing-issue-on-github/60066508#comment132437154_60066508) to the discussion:

"[GitHub Action: Pull request 'development' object/data, aka linked issues](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/34172)"

And Ismosh's [Marketplace action for finding the linked issues of a pull request](https://github.com/Ismoh-Games/find-linked-issues).

```yaml
    - name: Find linked issues
      id: find-linked-issues
      uses: Ismoh-Games/find-linked-issues@v0.0.1
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        repository: ${{ github.repository }} # optional
        pull-request-number: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }} # optional
        copy-issues-labels: true # optional
```

Comment: Search API sounds promising. I still don't understand why it isn't in REST API pull requests, but nice to know!

Comment: @Ismoh You might try the [search syntax for linked issues and pull requests](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-for-linked-issues-and-pull-requests) with the official GitHub CLI [`gh pr list --search <query>`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_list).

Answer (score 3):

in case you use 2-factor-auth with github you'll need to provide the authtoken as header in the request:

```
curl -u "<your_username>:<your_pw>" \
     --header 'X-GitHub-OTP: <your_authtoken>' \
     --request POST \
     --data '{"issue":"<issue_nr>", "head":"<your_username>:<your_forks_branchname>", "base":"<upstream_branch>"}' \
     https://api.github.com/repos/<upstream_user>/<upstream_repo>/pulls
```

Comment: Yes, 2FA prevents many of the answers here from working.  In my case, I created a personal access token and use it rather than my password, which works.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use [Gub](http://github.com/owahab/gub) to submit pull requests for your issue.

It also helps you use a proper fork/pull-request style.

Edit: 10/5/2013

To get Gub to submit pull-request for issue #123, you need to run the following:

```
$ gub start 123
```

This will create a new branch issue-123. Once you're done working on the issue, execute:

```
$ gub finish
```

Voila!

Note: I am the author of Gub gem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [git-hub](https://github.com/sociomantic/git-hub) tool, you could do this with:

`$> git hub pull attach 123`

This would convert issue #123 into pull request #123, thus maintaining all discussion about the issue in a single location.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2FA enabled, you can use pass the token with HTTPie:

```
http POST \
    https://api.github.com/repos/<repo-owner>/<repo-name>/pulls \
    issue=2 head=issue_2 base=master
    "Authorization:token PUTAUTHTOKENHERE"
```

This will use the branch `issue_2` to convert issue #2 into a pull request.