# How to modify GitHub pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I've opened a pull request to a project. The maintainer has decided to accept it, but told me to modify some contents.

How can I do it? Whether I should keep the commit hash unchanged, how can I do it?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Just push more commits on to the branch the request is for. The pull request will pick this up then.

## Example:

If you want to have b merged into master

1. You push c1,c2,c3 to b
2. then you make a new request for b
3. it gets reviewed and you need more commits
4. You push c11,c21,c31 to b
5. The pull request now shows all 6 six commits

Comment: Is possible to add commits to this pull request by someone other, except the author of this pull request?

Comment: everybody who pushes to the specific branch

Comment: @Daij-Djan very often if somebody makes a Pull Request, he pushes to his own fork of the repository. Is it possible to add commits to such a PR by people not having commit access to his fork?

Comment: @skywinder maybe you could check this question: [Is it possible to change other people's code in pull requests (Github)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061191/is-it-possible-to-change-other-peoples-code-in-pull-requests-github)

Comment: @MaciekŁoziński the answer is also only if "you [can] push to the specific branch" :)

Answer (score 53):

I just had one commit in a pull request, and I used `git commit --amend` to update it.  I then did a force push with `git push -f` so my amended commit replaced the original one.  The pull request automatically picked up the new commit.  (It actually showed both commits, but when I reloaded the page the old commit had gone.)

So while a forced push is generally not recommended, it can be useful for pull requests.  It's not recommended because if someone bases a commit on top of yours then they will have to do a rebase after your change.  But since nobody should be basing their work on an under-review pull request, it should be pretty safe in this situation.

Answer (score 11):

If you continue to make changes and keep pushing to the same branch, the refined commits will be added to the same pull request (unless your pull request has been merged). This could make the history very cluttered.

An alternate solution and a technique that I use is as follows:

1. Create a new branch (fixes) from the repository(upstream) and branch (develop) to which you intend to send the pull request by doing:

   git branch fixes upstream/develop
2. Add your refined commits directly to this newly created branch.

   git commit -m "your message"
3. Push this branch to your own forked remote (could be named origin).
4. Compare and send in a new pull request with clean commit history.
5. Also, it is a good idea to delete your branch after the pull request has been merged.
6. And you can comment and close your earlier pull requests.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use [github api](https://api.github.com).

#### example with [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)

```
curl --user "your_github_username" \
     --request PATCH \
     --data '{"title":"newtitle","body":"newbody",...}' \
     https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number
```

you can find the detailled list of data in [github developer doc](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#update-a-pull-request)

#### example : change name of [my pull request](https://github.com/Gregwar/Cache/pull/9)

```
curl --user "jeremyclement" \
     --request PATCH \
     --data '{"title":"allows the control of files and folders permissions."}' \
     https://api.github.com/repos/Gregwar/Cache/pulls/9
```

Comment: I tried to [change branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081053/how-to-change-the-base-branch-of-a-pull-request) but I think `head/label` and `head/ref` are not editable.

Answer (score 0):

Apply your changes over top of your existing branch where the PR is created. For example if you branch name is `newFeature` and you have create PR to merge `newFeature` into `develop` branch. Apply the suggested changes on the newFeature branch with as many commits you want. Once you are completed with fixing suggested review changes. Allow the reviewer to re-review it. Once approved you should be able to merge your PR.

You can use SourceTree or some GUI tool if you need help in general with git.