# Attach a pull request to someone ELSE's issue

Tags: git, github

On github, I usually attach pull requests to issues **I have** created using the technique here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11975092/522806

However, I want to attach a pull request to an issue **someone else** has created. The technique mentioned in the aforementioned thread does not work on issues I did not create and returns an error message stating I am unauthorized. Is there another way do this, preferably through github.com?

Thanks!

Comment: have you simply tried it?

Comment: Yes, I have. I cannot attach a pull request to an issue not created by me.

Comment: why didn't you mention this in your question? that's quite relevant information since it rules out the method you quoted

Comment: Your wish is my command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t think that possible, but you can make sure they are linked by including a commit that says `fixes #**issue-nr**` in your pull request.

Comment: All right. In the author's issue, will we see the details behind my pull request (i.e. additions/deletions), so we can easily inspect whether the issue was resolved appropriately?

Comment: No, the will only see a link to your pull request. But if your pull request gets merged, the issue will be closed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. I have used [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4529172/28804) to attach a pull request created by someone else in the same organization, but I think it should work for any pull request you're allowed to write to. (Note that the technique linked above is slightly different from the one you linked; the one you linked should work as well, but I've only done it using the one above.)

Comment: Darn. The command did not work on an issue not created by me. I get a message back basically saying "Validation Failed" and "unauthorized".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have write access to the repository that the pull request came from you can't update it directly.  But you can create a pull request to the repository that they made the pull request from!  Then the original PR creator can merge your pull request into their code and it automatically gets updated on the pull request.

From an admin's perspective I wish there was a way to update the pull request without getting permission from the original requester (who may not log in again).  I end up pulling to my private repo, making the changes I want and then creating a separate PR just to deal with the first PR.