# How do you attach a new issue to an existing pull request on github?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, issue-tracking

There are questions and answers specifying how do the opposite [*new pull request* to an *existing issue*](https://help.github.com/articles/opening-an-issue-from-code/).

I created a pull request on Github before opening an issue. Now I would like to assign an issue to this PR (i.e. a better way to start the conversation about what/why/how I am proposing a fix).

How to I create new issue for an **existing pull request** or create the issue then assign it?

I.e get the issue will show the box with:

> *user* referenced this issue from another pull request
>
> **# *Title of PR***

Can this be done without committing more changes to the PR?

Comment: The opposite on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528869/how-do-you-attach-a-new-pull-request-to-an-existing-issue-on-github

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I create a new issue for an existing pull request or create the issue then assign it?

There is no such thing than assignment in GitHub, just issue referencies.

But you could create the issue and then easily add a link by just adding a comment in your pull request referring to the new issue using the synthax `#idIssue` (ie `#1286`)

Comment: Ah, I thought there was a stronger link but yes references was all i was after. Also what threw me is they are one directional so from the issue I got the PR to show  _user referenced this pull request from another issue_ until I added the comment on the PR

Comment: And **after** the PR is merged the issue can say _user closed this issue in #x y months ago_

Answer (score 1):

Check if the new GitHub feature "[Open a new issue from a pull request review comment](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-10-10-open-issue-from-review-comment/)" applies to you (valid from Oct. 2018 only)

> Often pull request reviews surface conversations and follow-up actions that you want to act on seamlessly.
>   **Now you can click Open new issue within the pull request review comment’s options menu to open a new issue which will include a reference to the original comment**.